# What is the standard deviation of the proportion of heads in $25$ tosses?

Tags: probability

Is the formula for variance of proportion: $$\frac{\theta (1-\theta )}{n}$$

Is yes, then what does $\theta$ stand for exactly?

Answer (score 0):

$\theta$ (here) is the probability of one event in a dichotomous (two possibility) outcome - in this case, heads and tails.

So $\theta$ can be probability of a head coming up in a single toss. It's $\frac 12$ in an unbiased coin, but can be different with a loaded coin, of course.

$\theta$ can also represent probability of a tail coming up in a single toss- the formula is symmetric in $\theta$ and $1- \theta$, these two being probabilities of complementary outcomes.